# Security: minimizing the amount of 'inside' information revealed client side

Tags: meteor

I'm learning Meteor. What I understand so far is that to get the full range of benefits of Meteor's *Full Stack Reactivity* and *Latency Compensation*, we've got to put *Data on the Wire* and the *Database Everywhere*. So I'm wondering if it's the intention of the Meteor devs to have some sensitive information in the open on the client side even though modification of that information can only be done by authorized users, and only in authorized contexts. I mean, I'm aware that the `autopublish` and `insecure` packages should be removed, `Meteor.methods()` defined and `allow`, `deny` callbacks set and all that. But, the pattern I've seen so far is to define database collections in the `/lib` folder where they'll be accessible to both the server and the client. Obviously someone interested in my code will be able to see all the collections that I have in my database, and their names, just by taking a peek at that `/lib` folder. And if I'm using the SimpleSchema package to define schemas for those collections, I've just given the snooper a complete map of the app's database.

Of course, with solid methods and allow/deny rules, he ideally shouldn't be able to do anything sinister with that information. Still, that kind of inside information is very valuable. What approaches are other devs who are more knowledgeable and experienced with Meteor than I am taking to mitigate this?

Comment: Being concerned that users have access to your database schema when they also have access to the source code of your app is a little like giving a pistol to a child and worrying she'll get splinters from the grip. It's a lot more important that users (a) not see documents they shouldn't (publishers need to do the right thing) and (b) not modify documents they shouldn't (methods/allow/deny).

Comment: I know. But in other frameworks, a malicious user can view all of the app's source code, but he can't view the database schema. In this context, he can see **both** the source code and the database schema and that's just too much information. It's highly unlikely that the core Meteor devs couldn't foresee a situation like this so there must be a more secure implementation which I'm not aware of yet -- I'm a beginner in this stuff after all. So how are other devs doing it?

Comment: They aren't. How can you hide the schema if a user can read the source which manipulates it? The short answer is that if [Emily Stark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79uMp-S23MA) doesn't think this is a security concern, then neither do I. If, however, you can construct an attack vector which uses schema information and bypasses properly written methods and publishers (those which check for injection attacks), the I promise you the core devs would love to hear about it. :)

Comment: You can define which fields are sent to the client and work with sensitive fields in server-only code if you want. The idea behind using MongoDB tends to be that your database schema reflects the actual data structures you want to work with in your code. In other words, the schema of your database should generally be no more sensitive than the structure of results returned by a JSON API. When the technology is secure by design, you don't need security through obscurity. You're at more risk of an attacker finding a method that doesn't validate all of its arguments to prevent MongoDB injection.